# android slide up view panel like sms

Tags: android, sms, chat, slideup, bottom-sheet

I'm new to android and I want to create a chat application in android.
So far I have designed bottom of the edit text with submit button. 
like blow link

[image]

But I want to have a design like below link images when I click attach button.

I want to create like this layout:

[image]

can anybody know how to design like above link? Is it able to design with bottom sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel this sliding up library. It may not solve your requirement but you can get an idea

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        // this relative layout will be ur root layout

        // Add all your design elements here

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="Your Required Size">


        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then create a seperate ViewPager layout and , on submit button click load and clear the fragment , you will need to write logic for the ViewPager Seperately